# how to use Choreographer to synch animation with VSync?

Tags: android, android-studio, animation, vsync

When I use Choreographer I was thinking that it's will fire the doFrame every 16 ms to synch with the vSynch. But seam it's not the case when I look the log :

```
04-04 01:02:13.430: I/doFrame(5348): 83955391747085
04-04 01:02:13.443: I/doFrame(5348): 83955405796564
04-04 01:02:13.451: I/doFrame(5348): 83955413367397
04-04 01:02:13.461: I/doFrame(5348): 83955421952814
04-04 01:02:13.468: I/doFrame(5348): 83955430145522
04-04 01:02:13.474: I/doFrame(5348): 83955438113751
04-04 01:02:13.497: I/doFrame(5348): 83955460370652
04-04 01:02:13.515: I/doFrame(5348): 83955477302114
04-04 01:02:13.532: I/doFrame(5348): 83955494233669
04-04 01:02:13.549: I/doFrame(5348): 83955511161610
```

As you can see their is much less than 16ms between each call to doframe. So now I don't understand how Choreographer work :( What exactly mean calling Choreographer.postFrameCallback ? how it's possible that it's can be only 7ms between 2 doFrame event ?

Comment: Just FYI: [Drawn out: How Android renders (Google I/O '18)](https://youtu.be/zdQRIYOST64)

Comment: @MorrisonChang thanks, i see this but it's not explain why my choregrapher doframe is called with 7 ms interval instead of 16 ms :(

Comment: Are you testing on emulator or device (which may have display greater than 60Hz)

Comment: no, on a true mobile phone. but I notice also that the value of doFrame frameTimeNanos is always espaced of around 16 ms so i don't understand what this mean :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

120fps screens exist, and on Android it's been a while! Also, 120fps computers exist, and I suspect emulators can also be 120fps on those computers. For those devices, the interval between frames is 120th of a second, which is about 8ms, close to the 7ms you're getting.

So yeah, every time you read or heard something like "you got less than 16ms to do everything you need to do on the main thread, including rendering", that became a lie several years ago.